# can we use the toHaveScreenshot() and toMatchSnaphot() out side the test

Tags: playwright

Can we use the `toHaveScreenshot()` and `toMatchSnaphot()` outside the test without using config file only simple install NPM i playwright in package.json

I have already one snapshot I want to compare snapshot using toHaveScreenshot() method but I am confused we can use outside the test context?

```
const { chromium } =require( "playwright");

const example = async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://zversal.com/");
 
  await page.toHaveScreenshot("zeversal.png", {
    fullPage: false,
    maxDiffPixelRatio: 0.24,
  });
};
example();
```

Console reports error:

> toHaveScreenshot() must be called during the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Afaik, `toHaveScreenshot()` is part of the `@playwright/test` package.

If I'm looking at [the `Page` API docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page) there's no `toHaveScreenshot()` listed. I'd say it's only available in combination with Playwright Test and it's provided `expect` method.

```
await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot();
```

Answer (score 0):

As [similarly noted by `stefan judis` in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75295303/), `toHaveScreenshot` is an assertion matchers method provided by `expect` which comes from the Playwright Test library and is made to be used inside tests.

While that assertion can’t be used, you can still [take screenshots using Playwright](https://playwright.dev/docs/screenshots), and then compare them manually or with another tool.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's possible to use it outside of testing, but you can create a PlaywrightDevPage helper class to encapsulate common operations on the page.

Simple Usage =>

```
    // models/PlaywrightDevPage.js
    class PlaywrightDevPage {
      /**
       * @param {import('playwright').Page} page 
       */
      constructor(page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.getStartedLink = page.locator('a', { hasText: 'Get started' });
        this.gettingStartedHeader = page.locator('h1', { hasText: 'Installation' });
        this.pomLink = page.locator('li', { hasText: 'Playwright Test' }).locator('a', { hasText: 'Page Object Model' });
        this.tocList = page.locator('article div.markdown ul > li > a');
      }
      async getStarted() {
        await this.getStartedLink.first().click();
        await expect(this.gettingStartedHeader).toBeVisible();
      }
    
      async pageObjectModel() {
        await this.getStarted();
        await this.pomLink.click();
      }
    }
    module.exports = { PlaywrightDevPage };
```

More Info => [PlaywrightDevPage](https://playwright.dev/docs/pom#implementation)

Comment: Thank you, but you have any idea how to visually compare screenshot my problem statement is simple I have one screenshot and I have one URL of same website I want to check what is difference after change content using playwright toHaveScreenshot() and Match Snapshot() function